# How Can a Class Member Value From a GebSpec Base Class

Tags: spock, geb

I'm currently trying to create a `GlobalExtension` for my Geb-Spock framework. So far here is my extension:

```
class OnFailureListener extends AbstractRunListener {

    private final String id

    private final SauceREST sauceREST

    public OnFailureListener(String id, String username, String accessKey) {
        this.id = id
        this.sauceREST = new SauceREST(username, accessKey)
    }

    def void error(ErrorInfo error) {
        println error;
        this.sauceREST.updateJobInfo(this.sessionIdProvider.getSessionId(), "failed")
     }
}

class ResultExtension extends AbstractGlobalExtension {

    protected final String username = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME")
    protected final String accesskey = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY")
    protected final String sessionId

    @Override
    void visitSpec(SpecInfo specInfo) {
        specInfo.addListener(new OnFailureListener(sessionId, username, accesskey))
        }
 }
```

My issue is that the `sesssionId` value gets assigned in the `GebSpec` base class I'm using for other specs, and cannot be assigned directly in the extension class. Beyond using some gnarly reflection approaches, is there a way to access the `sessionId` value assigned in the base class in the extension? I'd also like to avoid using an `AnnotationExtension` since I'd like to apply this globally without modifying any spec code (similar to a JUnit `TestWatcher` pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you would be to write the `sessionId` into a shared `ThreadLocal` that can be accessed by your listener and the spec, otherwise you'll have to implement an `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IMethodInterceptor` so that you can gain access to the actual test instance to extract the field value.

Comment: FWIW, an example of using `IMethodInterceptor` as Leonard suggests can be seen in Geb's `ReportingOnFailureExtension`(see [here](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/3e0ada5065856a7ef1576eae5f25fdcf0e41bb7e/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/ReportingOnFailureExtension.groovy#L32) and [here](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/3e0ada5065856a7ef1576eae5f25fdcf0e41bb7e/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/ReportingOnFailureExtension.groovy#L34)) and [`OnFailureReporter`](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/OnFailureReporter.groovy#L30).